# call a file from child project bin folder to parent project in window form application using c# code

Tags: c#, winforms

i have two projects in one solution:

```
    : (Solution)Myapplication

    : project 1
           ReadMsgtxt.cs

    : project 2
          bin
            debug
               Msg.txt
```

now i want to read "Msg.txt" file from "ReadMsgtxt.cs". Main parent project is "project1" but i want read file from parent project to child project. I don't want hardcode the path. please suggest using c# code to retrieve the file

Comment: How to do you want copy the file , its in Build time or runtime

Comment: no i dont want copy the file.. just read the file data at runtime.. Actually i an using this code in ReadMsgtxt.cs but it is taking current file path i.e., project1 path
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Msg.txt");